# Split string in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've the following string that I would like to split and given in rows.

Example values in my column are:

```
['10000', '10001', '10002', '10003', '10004']
```

Using the SPLIT function, I get the following result:

[image]

I've two questions:

1. How do I split it so that I get '10000', instead of ['10000'?
2. How do I remove the Apostrof `'` ?

Response:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example

```
with t as (
  select ['10000', '10001', '10002', '10003', '10004'] col   
)
select cast(item as int64) num
from t, unnest(col) item
```

Above is assumption that col is array. In case if it is a string  - use below

```
with t as (
  select "['10000', '10001', '10002', '10003', '10004']" col   
)
select cast(trim(item, " '[]") as int64) num
from t, unnest(split(col)) item
```

Both with output

[image]

Comment: The second option only outputs the first two elements... am I missing something?

Comment: what you mean by "first two"? as you can see from above it outputs all five! :o) please clarify

Comment: Please see the updated question. I added a response there

Comment: i cannot reproduce what you see. I would recommend you to reload bq console (it is quite buggy recently) and try again!